# maximum memory memcached can handle

Tags: memory-management, configuration, memcached

I was looking for the maximum memory that Memcached can handle and how can I configure this property if there is such an option. So far, only thing I could find was the maximum size of the object that Memcached can handle but it is different from what I am looking for.

So, to keep it brief, what is the maximum memory that I can allocate for Memcached and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allocate any amount of memory if you have. Run memcached with -m parameter to limit your memory. See the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer)

Comment: Thank you. The document says **Note carefully that this isn't a global memory limit, so memcached will use a few % more memory than you tell it to**. So, assuming I have a server with 40 GB RAM, is it O.K. to set maximum value to 35 or do you suggest a much *safer* value?

Comment: Yes. It's safer. What Memchaced documentation say is what you are allocating is only applying for the caching purpose. Memcached it self use little bit more memory. Don't forget to leave some grace memory for operating system too.